# Is there a module to show a quick message to a user or role?

Tags: 7

Is there a module to send a user or users having a role a message like the one that is currently on top of this site (*The Drupal Answers 2012 community moderator election is underway — nominations now being accepted.*")?

I don't need a message box like the one that Private message module provides, but a quick message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [User Alert](http://drupal.org/project/user_alert) Module. This module provides a simple way to show a short-term urgent message on the website. Think of CNN Breaking News, when they show a short message the top of the site (or the 'Welcome!' style messages at StackExchange websites). This module works for both anonymous and authenticated users by using a cookie, and recording actions in the database. This solves the need to show messages independent of the users authenticated status. With User Alerts, you can: Alert users about breaking news, or a special same-day sale for ecommerce. You can also set expiration timers for alerts (1 hour, 3 hours, Never, etc) (Drupal 6 Only, D7 requires Scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a module, but VIEWS could be used to do something very similar.  Create a content type, say "motd," and to get fancy, put in a date field.  Then create a view with a block display, filtering on node type motd and the date field equal to today, and displaying the body of the node, then put that block where you want your message of the day to go...